# javascript varible grow on loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hare is my current function

```
    var listItems = $("#list_li").children();
    var count = listItems.length;

    var i;


    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

        const the_i = i;

        $("#news_" + the_i + " h2").click(function () {    
                $('#news_' + the_i + ' article').addClass('active');
                $('#news_' + the_i + ' h2').addClass('active');
                $('#news_' + the_i + ' img').addClass('active');
                $('#news_' + the_i).addClass('active');
                If is clicked.
                $('#news_1 article').removeClass('active');
                $('#news_1 h2').removeClass('active');
                $('#news_1 img').removeClass('active');
                $('#news_1').removeClass('active');
            }
        }); 
    }
```

My code adds up styles to it on click, it works fine, how ever, **I need to make it so it would know if its clicked or not**, I am using loop, because its news feed and it can get more and more, so without the struggle automatically know what to align.

I need something like this

```
var autoIncresingVar.i = 0;
```

so when it comes to the 1st one on loop, it would set it to 1 and on click check with "if" its clicked or not.

Let me try to explain *Note that I know its not real code*

```
each(i > 5) {
    var newEl_"i" = 0;

    on first element click 
        if {newEL_1 == 0) {
            addClasses
            newEL_i = 1;
        } else if)newEl_1 == 1) {
            removeClasses
            newEL_i = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.toggleClass()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function for check if the current node has the 'active' class. If yes, remove it. Else, add it.
Example :

```
$("#news_" + the_i + " h2").click(function () {
    if (!$('#news_' + the_i).hasClass('active'))
    {
        $('#news_' + the_i + ' article').addClass('active');
        $('#news_' + the_i + ' h2').addClass('active');
        $('#news_' + the_i + ' img').addClass('active');
        $('#news_' + the_i).addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#news_1 article').removeClass('active');
        $('#news_1 h2').removeClass('active');
        $('#news_1 img').removeClass('active');
        $('#news_1').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot, now I will know that I can check if it has the class, simple yet usefull. :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `.data()` to set a property at an object where value is toggled between `0` and `1` at each `click` event

```
  $("#news_" + the_i + " h2").data("clicked", 0)
  .on("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).data().clicked) {
      // do stuff with `$(this).data().clicked` : `0`
    } else {
      // do stuff with `$(this).data().clicked` : `1`
    }
    // set `$(this).data().clicked` to `1` or  `0`
    $(this).data().clicked = !$(this).data().clicked ? 1 : 0;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

        const the_i = i;

        $("#news_" + the_i + " h2").click(function () {    
                $('#news_' + the_i + ' article').toggleClass('active');
                $('#news_' + the_i + ' h2').toggleClass('active');
                $('#news_' + the_i + ' img').toggleClass('active');
                $('#news_' + the_i).toggleClass('active');

            }
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the add attribute function to add an on click event to each element
http://coursesweb.net/jquery/add-change-remove-attribute-jquery